# Vertical aligning content in :before pseudoelement

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay on some links that will show a magnifying glass as an overlay when you hover over it.

For simplicity, I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rw4hngvj/1/

I'm able to get the magnifying glass icon centered horizontally, but I can't center it vertically, it's always at the top of the element. I've tried setting `vertical-align:middle` and `top:50%`, but neither of those work.

One restriction I have is that I can't change the HTML at all, and I can only change the css for the `:before` pseudoelement.

Is there any way I can center the content of `:before`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to `.caption:before`.

You need to use the position property along with top.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these properties to your :before element, should center it. (based on your current code) Explanation below.

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

**Position: absolute is KEY.**

Using a combination of position:absolute, left: 0, right: 0, and margin: 0 auto (this is like saying: margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto, margin-top/bottom: 0) centers your element horizontally.

And using position: absolute, top: 50%, transform: translateY(-50%) centers your element vertically.

There are other ways to do this, but this is the quickest way that requires no modification to your current CSS.

Your final css for caption:before should look like this:

```
.caption:before {
    content: "\f002";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `position` `.caption:before`

```
.caption:before {
    content: "\f002";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */    
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rw4hngvj/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flexbox, just try this one

```
.caption
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:both;
    align-items:center;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a.tile
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;    
    background-color: green;
}
.caption
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.caption:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.caption:before {
    content: "\f002";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a class="tile">
  <div class="caption">
  </div>
</a>
<a class="tile">
  <div class="caption">
  </div>
</a>
```